# Node js can't connect to local database

Tags: mysql, node.js, localhost, mamp

I have a node js App, and when i try to run the node js using local database (mysql) and i use mamp and the error shown `Localhost refuse to connect` and log shown `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`. But when i try running the node js using db in server is fine.

**app.js**

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

function Connection() {

this.pool = null;

var konek = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'wmc_wahana'
};

this.init = function() {
    this.pool = mysql.createPool(konek);
}

this.acquire = function(callback) {
    this.init();
    this.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};
}
module.exports = new Connection();
```

**server.js**

```
var app = require('./app');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var port = '8080';

http.listen(port, function() {
   console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

thank you

Comment: can you try with different port number?

Comment: Please try port 8181 and also confirm your password is root or blank

Comment: Hello @Ratri I have edit your code please check

Comment: i have try different port but still same :( @KalleshwarKalshetty

Comment: what code have you edited? i dont see sir, please tell me @AnandChoudhary

Comment: Avoid `callbacks` and use `promises` if possible with `async`  and `await`. It makes the code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Where do you use `connection.Init()` and `connection.acquire`?

Answer (score 1):

pls change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"